# How to fix this "OutOfMemoryException", why do I get it since I use only 4/16 GB?

Tags: c#, graphics, out-of-memory

at the moment I do learn C# in an 8 week course. I have one small programm that will get me only an OutOfMemoryException.

But I really do not know why this Exception is called. I mean that the Windows Task Manager shows that I use only 4 of 16 GB RAM. Even if I try to test this programm after I restart the computer.

I have one form that should to the work ... but I do not see the mistake.

Following you will see the code of the only Button in this application.

```
private void cmdAuswahl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Graphics z = CreateGraphics();
  Font df = new Font("Verdana", 11);
  SolidBrush pinsel = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

  OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
  Image bild;

  z.Clear(BackColor);

  ofd.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Temp";
  ofd.Title = "Bitte eine Bilddatei wählen";
  ofd.Filter = "Bild-Dateien (*.jpg; *.gif)|*.jpg; *.gif";

  if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {
     bild = Image.FromFile(ofd.FileName);
     z.DrawImage(bild, 20, 40);
     z.DrawString("Breite: " + bild.Width + ", Höhe: " +
     bild.Height, df, pinsel, 20, 20);
  }
  else
     MessageBox.Show("Keine Bilddatei ausgewählt");
}
```

I start the application with "crtl + f5" and click on the button. 
After this I select one image.jpg with 122 KB.

after this I get the OutOfMemoryException

Informationen über das Aufrufen von JIT-Debuggen
anstelle dieses Dialogfelds finden Sie am Ende dieser Meldung.

```
************** Ausnahmetext **************
System.OutOfMemoryException: Nicht genügend Arbeitsspeicher.
   bei System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(String filename, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement)
   bei System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(String filename)
   bei ZeichnenBild.Form1.cmdAuswahl_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\CSharp\Kurs\W6T1 - 7-01\Zeichnen\10.4.1_ZeichnenBild\ZeichnenBild\Form1.cs:Zeile 31.
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Geladene Assemblys **************
mscorlib
    Assembly-Version: 4.0.0.0.
    Win32-Version: 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1.
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll.
----------------------------------------
ZeichnenBild
    Assembly-Version: 1.0.0.0.
    Win32-Version: 1.0.0.0.
    CodeBase: file:///D:/CSharp/Kurs/W6T1%20-%207-01/Zeichnen/10.4.1_ZeichnenBild/ZeichnenBild/bin/Debug/ZeichnenBild.exe.
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly-Version: 4.0.0.0.
    Win32-Version: 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1.
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll.
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly-Version: 4.0.0.0.
    Win32-Version: 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1.
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll.
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly-Version: 4.0.0.0.
    Win32-Version: 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1.
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll.
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly-Version: 4.0.0.0.
    Win32-Version: 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1.
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll.
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly-Version: 4.0.0.0.
    Win32-Version: 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1.
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll.
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly-Version: 4.0.0.0.
    Win32-Version: 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1.
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll.
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing.resources
    Assembly-Version: 4.0.0.0.
    Win32-Version: 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1.
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_de_b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.resources.dll.
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms.resources
    Assembly-Version: 4.0.0.0.
    Win32-Version: 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1.
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_de_b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.resources.dll.
----------------------------------------
mscorlib.resources
    Assembly-Version: 4.0.0.0.
    Win32-Version: 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1.
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/mscorlib.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_de_b77a5c561934e089/mscorlib.resources.dll.
----------------------------------------

************** JIT-Debuggen **************
Um das JIT-Debuggen (Just-In-Time) zu aktivieren, muss in der
Konfigurationsdatei der Anwendung oder des Computers
(machine.config) der jitDebugging-Wert im Abschnitt system.windows.forms festgelegt werden.
Die Anwendung muss mit aktiviertem Debuggen kompiliert werden.

Zum Beispiel:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

Wenn das JIT-Debuggen aktiviert ist, werden alle nicht behandelten
Ausnahmen an den JIT-Debugger gesendet, der auf dem
Computer registriert ist, und nicht in diesem Dialogfeld behandelt.
```

[Picture of the Task Manager, open Application and the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3k8T.jpg)

Comment: Okay ... I do not know why but some Images in JPEG do work and other don't. WTF? That that work I can see a small Image in the windows explorer. But this that wont do not show this preimage.

Comment: Did you put this together yourself? It contains so many mistakes I guess there is no simple remedy. Step one: Everything that is unmanaged must be disposed of once you are done with it. Bitmaps/Images are notorious for thar. So, if you only want to draw the image `bild` once do dispose of it! The variable will be out of scope aftr the click event is done but the GSI+ resource will not be freed! Best put the whole code in a using clause..:

Comment: ..`using Bitmap bild = Image.FromFile(ofd.FileName)) {
     z.DrawImage(bild, 20, 40);
     z.DrawString("Breite: " + bild.Width + ", Höhe: " +
     bild.Height, df, pinsel, 20, 20);}`

Comment: ..but unless bild is huge this should not lead to an oom exception when clicking only a few times. But after a while it will. Other items one ought to dispose of are Font, Pen, Brush and then some.. Does this happen right away? How large is the image in pixels?

Comment: Since I mentioned 'many' mistakes, here is the next one: If you can see the image and minimize/maximize the form it will be  gone. Never use `control.CreateGraphics`! Never try to cache a `Graphics` object! Either draw into a `Bitmap bmp` using a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` or in the `Paint` event of a control, using the `e.Graphics` parameter..

Comment: This is part of an C# course that works with the book "Einstieg in C# mit VsiualStudio 2017" by Thomas Theis. It is the first time that he want to import an Image this way this is the lost basic example from the book. The next chapter is about using paint.

Comment: I would write it only this way since this i the way we used to do it in the course. But if I want to use somethi g new I would at first look into the api.

Comment: Ah, ok. Then 1st get rid of the exception..As it stands the code you posted runs fine here, so either the image is huge (in pixel dimensions) or Sohaib is on the right track or something else is going on..

Comment: I will need to read about Dispose ... it is not mentioned in the book and course or at least I can't remember and find it

Comment: simply add bild.Dispose(); after the drawstring. But I doubt this or changing the target (change Platformziel from x86 to anycpu) will help as they do not make any difference here.. There must be some other issue in you program. Does it crash with every image you pick?

Comment: Öh am I blind? I don't see any exception handling in this method. The exception message that I did post in this question was the exception that I did get but didn't understand. But yeah it could be that the picture was to big. Windows did not want to open them. I did tried some other images that will work.

Comment: I had 2 images from google pictures. Since it is only some application to learn and nothing that someone else will work with. Maybe there was something wrong with the picture. I did use new pictures and resized the app display and they work.

Answer (score 2):

looks like you are compiling as x86, x86 processes can't have more than 2GB of ram. Compile as x64. Also, for a single image this is too much memory, there is something unsual going on

Comment: Thank your for the help, were do I need to make the change?

Comment: Project Properties -> Build -> Target platform = x64

Comment: Thanks ... it had any cpu as target but the checkbox qas checked to prefer 32 bit. At the moment I think there was something wrong with the images. With new Images the code works.

Comment: @ChiruKaio My experience is that Windows memory manager will not allow single chunk bigger than `~1.25GByte` even if you got 2GB of free memory... for 32bit app on 64bit OS (running in WOW64). Sadly win32 uses signed 32bit ints somewhere in the memory management hence only  2GByte is usable instead of 4GByte...